# bindView switch-case performace issues

Tags: java, android, performance, switch-statement, android-cursoradapter

I'm currently writing an app that needs to set images in a `ListView` depending on what entry there is in my database.

I realized this via a switch-case directly in the `bindView()` method of my `customCursorAdapter`. Since `bindView` is called very often, my `ListView` begins to stutter and everything becomes slow. Is there any way to "outsource" this database-comparison? Here is my sourcecode:

```
public class customCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    public customCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor){
        super(context, cursor, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_listitems, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        // Find fields to populate in inflated template
        TextView brand = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listBrand);
        TextView model = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listModel);
        TextView lastMoved = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dateContent);
        TextView lastCharged = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lastChargedContent);
        ImageView brandPhoto = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.brandImage);
        // Extract properties from cursor
        String brandList = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Brand"));
        String modelList = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Model"));
        String lastMovedList = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("LastMoved"));
        String lastChargedList = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("LastCharge"));

            switch(brandList){
                case "Ferrari":
                    brandPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.ferrari);
                    break;
                case "Porsche":
                    brandPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.porsche);
                    break;
                case "VW":
                case "Volkswagen":
                    brandPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.volkswagen);
                    break;
                case "Mini":
                    brandPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.mini);
                    break;
                case "Audi":
                    brandPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.audi);
                    break;
                case "Aston Martin":
                    brandPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.aston);
                    break;
                case "Alpina":
                    brandPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.alpina);
                    break;
                case "Jeep":
                    brandPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.jeep);
                    break;
                case "Bentley":
                    brandPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.bentley);
                    break;
                case "Dodge":
                    brandPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.dodge);
                    break;
                case "Fiat":
                    brandPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.fiat);
                    break;
                case "Ford":
                    brandPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.ford);
                    break;
                case "Lexus":
                    brandPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.lexus);
                    break;
                case "Mercedes":
                    brandPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.mercedes);
                    break;
                case "Maybach":
                    brandPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.maybach);
                    break;
                case "Peugeot":
                    brandPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.peugeot);
                    break;
                case "Skoda":
                case "Škoda":
                    brandPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.skoda);
                    break;
                case "Rolls Royce":
                    brandPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.rolls);
                    break;
                case "Smart":
                    brandPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.smart);
                    break;
                case "Opel":
                    brandPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.opel);
                    break;
                case "Nissan":
                    brandPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.nissan);
                    break;
                case "Alfa Romeo":
                    brandPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.alfa);
                    break;
                case "BMW":
                    brandPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.bmw);
                    break;
                case "Seat":
                    brandPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.seat);
                    break;
                case "Lamborghini":
                    brandPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.lamborghini);
                    break;
                default: brandPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_directions_carhd);
            }

        // Populate fields with extracted properties
        brand.setText(brandList);
        model.setText(modelList);
        lastMoved.setText(lastMovedList);
        lastCharged.setText(lastChargedList);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a ViewHolder . And for images use a prefilled collection .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I can see from your code is, there is a one to one mapping with the brand and the image associated with it. I do not know why you are not putting the id of the resource in the database, so that you do not have to pass the `brandList` inside a `switch` case and compare each time you have to populate an image in each of your list item.

So I would suggest strongly, to keep the image name in the same database table from where you are fetching the other information. So that you just get the name of the image associated with the brand and then put it in your `ImageView` as an image resource.

So you need to do something like the following. At first prepare a `HashMap` containing the resource ids of your images.

```
String[] images = {"ferrari", "alpina", "porsche", "volkswagen", .......};
Map<String, Integer> brandImagesMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for(String imageName : images) {
    int drawableResourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", this.getPackageName());
    brandImagesMap.put(imageName, drawableResourceId);
}
```

Once your map is populated with the resource ids of your images in the constructor of your `customCursorAdapter` class, you can easily fetch the image resource id from the map efficiently and put it as the resource of your `ImageView`. Note that, I am assuming you are keeping the name of the image in a separate column in your database table.

```
String photoResourceName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Photo"));
brandPhoto.setImageResource(brandImagesMap.get(photoResourceName));
```

The code is not tested. Please modify as per your requirement.

**Update**

Use Glide for loading images in your `RecyclerView`. Its pretty simple to implement and of course efficient.

In your `bindView` function, just replace the code for loading image with the following.

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(brandImagesMap.get(photoCol))
    .fitCenter()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_directions_carhd)
    .into(myHolder.brandPhoto);
```

To know more about how to use Glide, please follow [this link](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

Comment: thanks a lot! Trying to implement this now. Thank you!

Comment: Please let me know if you could implement it successfully. You are most welcome. :)

Comment: It was helpful and i upvoted it, but i don't havce enough reputation yet to make it count. I provided another answer with your implemented idea but I'm still having problems. Could you take a look at it? See my answer

Comment: Please see the updated answer. I think this will resolve your issue. Thanks.

Comment: Worked! ListView now runs smoothly. Thank you!

Comment: Great to know that helped. Cheers!